# Are EntityMetadata classed or buddy file still relevant/best way to work?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Are EntityMetadata classed or  buddy file still relevant/best way to work?

- I am working directly with a database I don’t control and is
  maintained by a 3rd party company.
- Im going to assume there will be database changes in this, because I
  always assume bad stuff will happen.
- Im looking to use Entity Framework Code first from database .

I don’t want to put attributes in the models, when it will get overridden, when the database is updated and I have to recreate the models.

So are EntityMetadata classed or  buddy file still relevant/best way to work?  I find very few references to them and most are from 2011, so that made me raise an eyebrow.

For a good example see here https://hartzer.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/mvc-buddy-class/

Its also a little bit of duplicate code which feels bad

Comment: Why are you putting Presentation attributes on the Repository objects? My understanding is when you have a repository the attributes should be on Domain objects, not Repository objects. Then when the Repository changes you only have to update your Domain <-> Repository mappings.

Comment: If you do not have access or control of the database you are not really using code first, you are just using a tool to generate the models from an existing database. In this case you would have to use a buddy class to add your own attributes but really you shouldn't be adding them to the entities, just your view models. Honestly though I've never heard of a third party company giving access to their database. In this case they should be providing you an API to get the data you need. Adding attributes to an entity that you have no control of wouldn't do you any good any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want go back and answer this

I did not use EntityMetadata.

I have models in the repository projects that are decorated with all the nice entity framework attributes.  One project is code first as it uses my DB and the other and DB first as it uses a 3rd party project.

Then there is a service class that you just ask GetPerson(int ID) and it will go to what ever repository it need, or both for someone

HERE IS THE MAGIC BIT
On the MVC controller that asks for GetPerson it will use automapper to convert the object into a display object that has all the MVC attributes.

So if/when the 3rd party DB changes and I have to rebuild the models I shouldnt loose any other attributes.

Feel free to ask any questions or point out any flaws in this idea.